# Using data from two separate lists in one function?

Tags: c#, list

Basically I have a part of my program (it's for Vector solving) that is supposed to take data from two lists (listVectorMagnitude and listVectorAngle), and then run them through a function
in a separate class (vectorXComponent), and then return the value. How exactly would I go about taking the first value in listVectorMagnitude, the first value in listVectorAngle, and then use them as parameters in the vectorXComponent function? It would iterate over this process for as many values are in the lists. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the lists, using each pair of items as parameters for your function?

Comment: Could you post the code you currently have?

Comment: Show some code as an example of what you're trying to do so we can advise accordingly.  Are you asking how to pass values as arguments to a function?  If so, you may want to just pick up a book on learning C#.

Comment: As an aside: You may want to look into creating, or using, a vector class that incorporates both angle and magnitude.  It avoids the nasties that occur when your two lists have different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give a lot of detail. I'll assume that you have an instance of a class `Bar` named `bar`, and that class has a method named `vectorXComponent`. Additionally, I assume that the return type of `Bar.vectorXComponent` is `Foo`.

The modern functional way:

```
var xComponents = listVectorMagnitude.Zip(
                      listVectorAngle,
                      (x, y) => bar.vectorXComponent(x, y)
                  );
```

Or, an old-fashioned `for` loop:

```
List<Foo> xComponents = new List<Foo>();
for(int i = 0; i < listVectorMagnitude.Count; i++) {
    xComponents.Add(bar.vectorXComponent(
        listVectorMagnitude[i],
        listVectorAngle[i])
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I was going to add that I was thinking it might be similar to the Zip function in Python, but I wasn't sure.